# how do I calculate Prayer Times in kotlin or java?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, timezone

so I'm using this class:
 http://praytimes.org/code/git/?a=viewblob&p=PrayTimes&h=093f77d6cc83b53fb12e9900803d5fa75dacd110&hb=HEAD&f=v1/java/PrayTime.java
for getting the prayer times and I want to use it with the latitude and longitude I made with location permissions but when ever I change the value of the time zone I't doesn't give me the accurate prayer times for the city. 
is there any possible way to make the time zone works auto? so if a guy in Morocco uses my app the time zone changes to Morocco timezone automatically so the prayer times gives the accurate times? similarly if a guy lives in Saudi, Iraq, Spain..etc

thanks in advance.

**My code that I have problem with **

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun getLastLocation() {
    if (checkPermission()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {

            mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                var location: Location? = task.result
                if (location == null) {
                    requestNewLocationData()
                } else {

                    val resultimeZone = TimezoneMapper.latLngToTimezoneString(
                        location.latitude,
                        location.longitude
                    )
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cityName).text = resultimeZone
                    val latitude: Double = location.latitude
                    val longitude: Double = location.longitude
                    var timeZone = 3.00
                    val timeZoneId = timeZone.toString()
                    val prayTime = praytime()
                    prayTime.timeFormat = prayTime.time12 // getTime12 is protected
                    prayTime.calcMethod = prayTime.makkah // Makkah
                    prayTime.asrJuristic = prayTime.shafii // Shafii (standard)
                    prayTime.adjustHighLats = prayTime.angleBased
                    prayTime.timeZone = prayTime.timeZone
                    prayTime.computeMidDay(prayTime.dhuhrMinutes.toDouble())
                    val offsets = intArrayOf(
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ) // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}

                    prayTime.tune(offsets)
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId))
                    cal.time = Date()


                    val times: ArrayList<String> =
                        prayTime.getPrayerTimes(
                            cal,
                            latitude,
                            longitude,
                            timeZone
                        )
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Fajr).text = times.get(0)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sabah).text = times.get(1)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dhuhr).text = times.get(2)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.AzanTime).text = times.get(3)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maghreb).text = times.get(4)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Esha).text = times.get(6)

                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        requestPermission()
    }
```

You can use Java For Samples

Comment: I do not mean this to be insulting in anyway: return the prayer time in UTC (I know, so secular) and then let the user's device translate that to local time. Precisely so a user in Timbuktu does not have to change their timezone to match yours. Which, if they were going to change their timezone anyway, I would assume they would choose Mecca and skip your program entirely. BTW, Mecca is UTC+3 hours.

Comment: which prayer time?

Comment: Again, not to be insulting, all of them! Why is one prayer different from another? (I know, terrible phrasing).

Comment: do you mean that I should change the prayertime class or what? also can u give me a sample on how to do it?

Comment: FYI, the `Calendar` & `Date` classes are terribly flawed. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. I would strongly suggest finding a calculation library based on *java.time* rather than the legacy classes used by your current library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891905/12478830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after some time I was able to solve this problem at the moment.

first you need this library to get the time zone,

[TimeZoneMapper](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drtimcooper/LatLongToTimezone/master/src/main/java/com/skedgo/converter/TimezoneMapper.java)

Then you should link this library to your time zone variable and then you should subtract the time zone by 4 like this:

```
 var TimeId = TimezoneMapper.latLngToTimezoneString(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                val gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeId).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)

                val z1 = gmt.substring(4)
                val z = z1.replace(":", ".")
                val zo = z.toDouble()
```

and that's it

**full code**

```
                    var TimeId = TimezoneMapper.latLngToTimezoneString(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                    val gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeId).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)

                    val z1 = gmt.substring(4)
                    val z = z1.replace(":", ".")
                    val zo = z.toDouble()
                    val latitude: Double = location.latitude
                    val longitude: Double = location.longitude
  val timeZoneId = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()
                    val prayTime = praytime()
                    prayTime.timeFormat = prayTime.time12 // getTime12 is protected
                    prayTime.calcMethod = prayTime.makkah // Makkah
                    prayTime.asrJuristic = prayTime.shafii // Shafii (standard)
                    prayTime.adjustHighLats = prayTime.angleBased
                    // my codes
                    prayTime.timeZone = prayTime.timeZone1
                    prayTime.setFajrAngle(18.5)

                    prayTime.computeMidDay(prayTime.dhuhrMinutes.toDouble())
                    val offsets = intArrayOf(
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ) // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}

                    prayTime.tune(offsets)
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId.toString()))
                    val now = Date()
                    cal.time = now



                        val times: ArrayList<String> =
                            prayTime.getPrayerTimes(
                                cal, latitude, longitude, zo
                            )
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Fajr).text = times.get(0)
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sabah).text = times.get(1)
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dhuhr).text = times.get(2)
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.AzanTime).text = times.get(3)
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maghreb).text = times.get(4)
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Esha).text = times.get(6)
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

For get timezone you can use this library easily: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drtimcooper/LatLongToTimezone/master/src/main/java/com/skedgo/converter/TimezoneMapper.java After that use `TimeZone.getTimeZone` Also for calculating prayer times, codes of this site are useful http://praytimes.org/code/

Comment: I understand your question, I asked similar question several days ago, It seems that you can't convert latitude and longitude directly to timezone, but by using the library I linked to you can convert latitude and longitude to name of timezone, for example "Asia/Tehran" and then TimeZone.getTimeZone shows you for example GMT+04:30 @Abood

Comment: can you plz give me an example  on how to do it ?

Comment: I gave you example in last comment @Abood